# Increase the height of recyclerview dynamically on item add

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[Display pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d1CU.png)

In my app, i want to increase the height of recycler view dynamically. As i add new item under complaints, the height of recycler view should increase. Is there a way to do it? Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complaint_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_line"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:text="Complaints"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorFullBlack" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/complaints_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/complaint_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
                android:divider="@color/toolBarBackground"
                android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructions_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_line"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:text="Instructions"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorFullBlack" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/instructions_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/instructions_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
                android:divider="@color/toolBarBackground"
                android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <in.palmpower.videocon.uicommon.widget.EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_text_field"
                    style="@style/FormEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/one_dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:inputType="textFilter"
                    android:padding="@dimen/search_edit_text_padding"
                    android:privateImeOptions="nm" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/edittext_hint_search"
                    android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
                    android:text="@string/add_button_string"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Christopher I have specified the height in xml. Nothing more than that.

Comment: set wrap_content on your recyclerview and your row item parent layout

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got stuck on same issue, i was using `RecyclerView` with `wrap_content` inside `LinearLayout`, i change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and it set `RecyclerView` Height Based On Children.

Comment: This really works for me after many hours of searching and trying.. Thank you

Comment: glad this helped.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView 
             = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.complaint_recycler_view);
int originalItemSize = iteList.size();

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();

if (itemList.size() > originalItemSize ){
    params.height = params.height + 100;
    originalItemSize  = itemList.size();
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to put teh recyclerview in any other layout (Relative layout is preferable). Then change recyclerview's height/width as match parent to that layout and set teh parent layout's height/width as wrap content. it works for me

Answer (score -1):

WRAP_CONTENT will not work if you want recyclerView to take part of screen.
If you want other content to be there below recyclerView, you can put recyclerView inside LinearLayout and use the following code to change the height dynamically.

I assume you are using a list(complaint_list) for storing complaints.Adjust the complaint_height accordingly

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();
int complaint_height=400;
if (complaints_list.size() > 2) {
params.height = ((complaint_list.size() - 1) * 100) + complaint_height;
} else {
  params.height = complaint_height+100;
}
mRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: have you placed recyclerView inside LinearLayout with wrap_content?